# Show GIF images in 9Gag style

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I like to know how to show a GiF file after clicking a JPG file just like in 9Gag.com

I'm using timthumb.php for JPG image.

```
https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/
```

Here is the code below

```
<div class="images">
<img alt="Image Title" src="timthumb.php?src=MyImage.jpg&amp;w=500&amp;q=100">
</div>
```

I want to show the original image after clicking this JPG. Can anyone point me out the way to do this using jQuery or JavaScripts.

Note: This is a image loop so there can be more then one image.

Really appropriate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the jQuery library.
**HTML**

```
<div class="images">
    <img class="thumb" alt="Image Title" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruR4z.png" gif="http://ourbunkers.0catch.com/grunt.gif"/>
    <img class="thumb" alt="Image Title" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruR4z.png" gif="http://ourbunkers.0catch.com/grunt.gif"/>
    <img class="thumb" alt="Image Title" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruR4z.png" gif="http://ourbunkers.0catch.com/grunt.gif"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".thumb").click( function(){ 
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("gif")); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PP42Q/8/

Comment: Just a tip: `$(".thumb").click( function(){  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("gif")); });` will do the work too :) Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PP42Q/6/